"union" to avoid duplicates
https://dbfiddle.uk/zspUa8WK
I need to export name and sum the invoice of my customer since 2022. So I need to get only customers which bought since 2 years and the sum.
No problem for that:
select i.customer_id, sum(amount)
from invoices i
inner join customer c2 on c2.customer_id = i.customer_id 
where i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022'
group by i.customer_id , c2.customer_id 




id
name
sum




2
Johnson
300


3
Ali
100



I need, in the same export, to get customer modified this year
I use this query
select c.customer_id, c.name,  '' from customer c 
where c.modificationDate > '01/12/2024'
group by c.customer_id , c.name




id
name





1
Smith



3
Ali




Because I need this in the same export, I use a UNION
select i.customer_id, c2.name , sum(amount) sum from invoices i
   inner join customer c2 on c2.customer_id =i.customer_id 
   where i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022'
   group by i.customer_id , c2.customer_id , c2.name 
union  
select c.customer_id, c.name,  '' from customer c 
where c.modificationDate > '01/12/2024'
group by c.customer_id , c.name 




id
name
sum




1
Smith
0.0000


2
Johnson
300.0000


3
Ali
0.0000


3
Ali
100.0000



My problem is that I would like that mister ALI be only once in my result, ie



id
name
sum




1
Smith
0.0000


2
Johnson
300.0000


3
Ali
100.0000



How could I do that?
DDL script for testing
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100) COLLATE French_CI_AS NULL,
    city varchar(100) COLLATE French_CI_AS NULL,
    modificationDate date NULL
);
INSERT INTO customer
(customer_id, name, city, modificationDate)
VALUES(1, N'Smith', N'NY', '2024-12-03 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO customer
(customer_id, name, city, modificationDate)
VALUES(2, N'Johnson', N'London', '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO customer
(customer_id, name, city, modificationDate)
VALUES(3, N'Ali', N'Bombay', '2024-12-05 00:00:00.000');

CREATE TABLE invoices (
    invoice_id int NOT NULL,
    customer_id int NULL,
    amount money NULL,
    invoice_date datetime NULL,
    CONSTRAINT invoices_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
);
INSERT INTO invoices
(invoice_id, customer_id, amount, invoice_date)
VALUES(1, 1, 100.0000, '2018-01-11 18:06:00.333');
INSERT INTO invoices
(invoice_id, customer_id, amount, invoice_date)
VALUES(2, 2, 200.0000, '2023-09-03 18:06:26.620');
INSERT INTO invoices
(invoice_id, customer_id, amount, invoice_date)
VALUES(3, 2, 100, '2023-06-14 18:07:17.350');
INSERT INTO invoices
(invoice_id, customer_id, amount, invoice_date)
VALUES(4, 3, 100, '2024-11-20 18:08:10.510');


Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete and consistent [mcve].

A UNION is not required. You can use 1 SELECT with a SUM of Amount when  i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022' and SUM 0 otherwise. In this solution the query must start with the customer table and the Invoices table will need to be add via a LEFT JOIN.
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, SUM(CASE WHEN i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) as Sum
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON c.customer_id =i.customer_id 
WHERE i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022' OR c.modificationDate > '01/12/2024'
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.name
ORDER BY c.Customer_ID

fiddle

Date's parameters should be in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd

Probably slightly more efficient to pre-filter invoices if indexing is in place LEFT JOIN invoices i ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id ON i.invoice_date > '2022-12-01' WHERE i.invoice_date IS NOT NULL OR c.modificationDate > '2024-12-01'

Perform the union first then apply the GROUP BY. For the modified records expose 0 as the amount.
SELECT t.customer_id , t.name, sum(t.amount) AS sum 
FROM
(  
    --customers invoiced since 01/12/2022 
    SELECT i.customer_id, c2.name, i.amount
    FROM invoices i
    INNER JOIN customer c2 ON c2.customer_id =i.customer_id 
    WHERE i.invoice_date > '01/12/2022'

    UNION

    --customers modified since 01/12/2024
    SELECT c.customer_id, c.name,  0 AS amount 
    FROM  customer c 
    WHERE c.modificationDate > '01/12/2024'
) t 
GROUP BY t.customer_id , t.name
ORDER BY t.Customer_ID

fiddle



customer_id
name
sum




1
Smith
0.0000


2
Johnson
300.0000


3
Ali
100.0000




The advantage of this answer (over the other where ... or ... approach) is that this query is sargeable (meaning that it can make efficient use of indexes and to avoid full table scans).

A slight variation of the above is to change 0 AS amount to null AS amount if the OP prefers a null sum for the no-activity cases. This would also allow calculation of count(t.amount) to count active invoices. Fiddle.
